# Python function returning only first value of a column data

Tags: python, function, csv

I have this function reading school names from a file but it only returns the first school name.
What do I do to make it return all names but if i use the print (sch) it prints all.Thanks

```
def school():
    schools_from_csv = pd.read_csv("School_data.csv", engine='python')
    cht = school_from_csv.school_name.str.strip()
    for sch in cht:
        return sch
        #prints(sch)

    return None

college=school()
```

Comment: What do you have the loop for? Just return `cht` once you created it.

Comment: all the names are already in cht, so just return that

Answer (score 0):

Since you've used return, the loop will be terminated when it finds the first element in cht.

To get the entire list, you may directly return cht.

```
def school():
    schools_from_csv = pd.read_csv("School_data.csv", engine='python')
    cht = school_from_csv.school_name.str.strip()
    return cht

college=school()
```

Or if you want the function to generate values one by one, you can use generators and change the for loop to.

```
for sch in cht:
     yield sch
```

You can read more about generators [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Comment: thanks for the quick response.I also noticed that.I am actually returning the argument to another function,how can i make it continue the loop to the end

Comment: whats the point of looping over `cht` and appending the items to `sch_list`. why not just return `cht`

Comment: You can add every element to a new list, and return the list at the end, as I've done.

Comment: @banji what do you mean with "continue to loop" at the end?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Yeah. I've changed that. You can use generator to loop through and get one value at a time.

Comment: @exhuma. There are 271 school names there, so i want it to pick each one from the beginning to the end and send  each one as arguments to another function.

Comment: @chrisdoyle the return cht returns it this way Name: school_name, Length: 271, dtype: object, with all the names and their corresponding index number.But i only need the names returned

Comment: @banji yes cause you have a pandas series, whats wrong with that? you can iterate it just like any other list

Comment: @banji if you really do insist or need it to be a list and not a pandas series then just do `cht = school_from_csv.school_name.str.strip().tolist()` and then return `cht`

Comment: @banji The solutions proposed here will all work. As long as your return-value from the function is iterable you're fine. So you can either use a Pandas series or convert it first to a list and *then* return it. Both will allow you to interate over the values.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle thanks your code works. I appreciate everyone that came to my aid. Cheers everyone

Comment: @ChrisDoyle' I just discovered a problem, i actually needed it in a for loop such that each school name read is used to search a database of schools in another search function.As it is now it brings all as a list to search a dictionary whereas when i use a for loop and it returns only one school it searches the database and gets all the info about that particular school

Comment: yes........so you can either pass this list to the function and it can iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) if you replace `return` with `yield`

```
def school():
    schools_from_csv = pd.read_csv("School_data.csv", engine='python')
    for sch in schools_from_csv:
        yield sch.school_name.str.strip()

    return None

college = school()
for col in college:
    print(col)
```

Or return list after the `for` loop

```
def school():
    schools = []
    schools_from_csv = pd.read_csv("School_data.csv", engine='python')
    for sch in schools_from_csv:
        schools.append(sch.school_name.str.strip())

    return schools
```

It also seems you want to loop on `schools_from_csv`, not `cht`

Comment: Wouldn't `list(cht)` create the same list you made in `schools`?

Comment: @Aryerez yes, assuming there are no more actions needed in the loop.

Comment: the error i encountered 'generator object Entity_name at 0x10847230'

Comment: I want to loop using the school_name column in the schools_from_csv

Comment: @banji where did you get it?

Comment: @guy i have this error using your code File "find29.py", line 42, in <module>
    for col in college:
  File "find29.py", line 38, in school
    yield sch.school_name.str.strip()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'school'

Answer (score 0):

This code, as shared by @ChrisDoyle, solved my problem:

```
def school():
    schools_from_csv = pd.read_csv("School_data.csv", engine='python')
    cht=schools_from_csv.school_name.str.strip().tolist()
    return cht 

school()
```